# How to run Scrapy Spider with cron Job Scheduling

Tags: python, cron, scrapy, schedule

I'm new to Python and web scraping. Pls excuse me for my ignorance. In this program, I want to run my spider on a schedule. I use Python 3.7 and MacOs.
I wrote cronjob using crontab and called shell script to run the scrapy spider. However it executed only once with the last line "INFO: Closing spider (finished)". Didn't repeat according to the schedule. I executed simple python script to test the schedule and then it worked. Seems this issue only with the spider. Please help to understand how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
import csv
import os
import random
from time import sleep
import scrapy


class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amspider"

    with open("data.csv", "a") as filee:
        if os.stat("data.csv").st_size != 0:
            filee.truncate(0)
        filee.close()

    def start_requests(self):
        list = ["https://www.example.com/item1",
                "https://www.example.com/item2",
                "https://www.example.com/item3",
                "https://www.example.com/item4",
                "https://www.example.com/item5"
                ]

        for i in list:
            yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse)
            sleep(random.randint(0, 5))

    def parse(self, response):
        product_name = response.css('#pd-h1-cartridge::text')[0].extract()
        product_price = response.css(
            '.product-price .is-current, .product-price_total .is-current, .product-price_total ins, .product-price ins').css(
            '::text')[3].extract()

        print(product_name)
        print(product_price)

        with open('data.csv', 'a') as file:
            itemwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

            itemwriter.writerow([str(product_name).strip(), str(product_price).strip()])

            file.close()
```

---

**amsp.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Users/amal/PycharmProjects/AmProj2/amazonspider 
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
export PATH
scrapy crawl amspider
```

---

**crontab**

Tried both ways But spider executed only once.

```
*/2 * * * * /Users/amal/Documents/amsp.sh

*/2 * * * * cd /Users/amal/PycharmProjects/AmProj2/amazonspider && scrapy crawl amspider
```

Comment: It would be best to separate these pieces.  Make sure that you can execute things properly without crontab before you bring the scheduler into it.

Comment: @XanderYzWich Thanx for the tip. Program works properly when I executed with "scrapy crawl amspider" on terminal. I executed simple python script from the same location with the cmd "python test.sh" as a cronjob and it worked well.

Comment: Did you check cron’s log?

Comment: @amal for the amsp.sh approach, I believe that you forgot the $ on your variable usage that should look like `export $PATH`

Comment: also I highly recommend that you but your shell scripts into /usr/local/bin or whatever location you consider your personal script directory.  Then make sure that location is added to $PATH permanently. Crontab that script call, and lastly add `cd -` at the end of your scripts so that if you call them from some other location (being on path allows this) then you wind up back in the directory where you started.